# Alterar "on" para "click" em função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero que quando eu click nos radios faça a chamada da função, atualmente esta assim.

```
$("input[name='txtCategoria']").on('blur', function(){
    var txtCategoria = $(this).val();
    $.get('buscar_tipos.php?txtCategoria=' + txtCategoria,function(data){
        $('#tipos').html(data);
    });
});
```

Porem so quando eu clico no radio e clico em outra parte da pagina que aparece a consulta, queria que quando clica-se ja executa-se, tentei assim.

```
$("input[name='txtCategoria']").on("click", function(){
    var txtCategoria = $(this).val();
    $.get('buscar_tipos.php?txtCategoria=' + txtCategoria,function(data){
        $('#tipos').html(data);
    });
});
```

Mas não funcionou, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`blur` quer dizer *"quando o elemento perder o foco"*. É isso que acontece quando clicas fora desse elemento, e a função corre. Porque ele "perdeu o foco".

O mais semântico seria usar o [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), que é quando o `input` mudar de valor. Assim, mesmo para quem navegue e mude o input com o teclado, a lógica vai funcionar.

```js
$("input[name='txtCategoria']").on("change", function() {
  $.get('buscar_tipos.php?txtCategoria=' + this.value, function(data) {
    $('#tipos').html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado, estou começando agora em JavaScript estou apanhando muito kkk.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo ainda bem que pude ajudar. Repara que usei `this.value`. Nesse código faz o mesmo, e mais rápido/simples que `$(this).value();`

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo Nota que o teu exemplo com `click` devia funcionar também (para cliques). Pode ser que precises de delegar o evento. Se tiveres problemas diz.

Comment: So fiz a alteração de blur para change e funcionou perfeitamente.